# Can SonarScanner for MsBuild scan TSQL

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonar-runner

I have SonarQube installed and we are trying to run it on a product that contains the following code types

- Javascript
- VBScript
- XML
- C#
- VB.net
- T/SQL

Now we have got it running to scan all the code apart from the T/SQL code.

This TSQL code sits under the same directory as all the other code but doesn't have a specific visual studio project.

The only way we have been able to run a scan on the SQL is using the standard `sonarqube` runner, but that causes a new product to be created on our dashboard.

Any thoughts or suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, if you want the TSQL files to be analyzed and appear under the same SonarQube project as the other code you will need to reference it from an MSBuild project.

There are a couple of ways you could do this:

1) include the TSQL files in one of your existing projects using a snippet like the following:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <!-- Include additional files that should be analyzed by the SonarScanner for MSBuild -->
  <None Include="*.tsql" >
    <!-- Don't show the items in the Solution Explorer -->
    <Visible>False</Visible>
  </None>
</ItemGroup>
```

2) Create a separate dummy MSBuild project whose only purpose is to specify the additional files to be analyzed. This is slightly more complicated as the dummy project needs some additional content to make it work with the SonarScanner for MSBuild targets.
The following template works with v4.3 of the scanner, and should work with recent previous versions too.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

  <!-- The only purpose of this project is to specify additional files to be analyzed by the SonarScanner for MSBuild -->

  <!-- 1. Set a unique GUID id for the project -->
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ProjectGuid>{EA2BAA27-D799-4FBE-9430-7499ACF3E431}</ProjectGuid>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <!-- 2. Specify the files to be analysed --> 
  <ItemGroup>
    <SonarQubeAnalysisFiles Include="**\*.js" />
  </ItemGroup>


  <!-- ******************************************************** -->
  <!-- Boilerplate - no need to change anything below this line -->
  <!-- ******************************************************** -->
  <!-- Import the SQ targets (will only exist if the scanner "begin" step has been executed) -->
  <PropertyGroup>
    <SQImportBeforeTargets>$(localappdata)\Microsoft\MSBuild\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.targets\ImportBefore\SonarQube.Integration.ImportBefore.targets</SQImportBeforeTargets>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Condition="Exists('$(SQImportBeforeTargets)')" Project="$(SQImportBeforeTargets)" />

  <!-- Re-define the standard step of targets used in builds -->
  <Target Name="Build" />
  <Target Name="Clean" />
  <Target Name="CoreCompile" />
  <Target Name="Rebuild" DependsOnTargets="Clean;Build" />

  <!-- Re-define one of the standard SQ targets as we have already set the list of files to analyze above -->
  <Target Name="CalculateSonarQubeFilesToAnalyze" >
    <PropertyGroup>
      <!-- Set a property indicating whether there are any files to analyze -->
      <AnalysisFilesExist Condition=" @(SonarQubeAnalysisFiles) != '' ">true</AnalysisFilesExist>
    </PropertyGroup>
  </Target>
</Project>
```